# Закрытие div'a при клике вне его

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте, для скрытия div'а, при клике вне его, использую такой вот код:

```js
$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
  var container = $("#");
  if (container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
    container.hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

При клике на "прокрутку" страницы, элемент закрывается. Подскажите, как это исправить?

P.S. Вопрос задавал ранее, но ответ мне не помог...

Comment: Полагаю, `$('document.body')`, вместо `$(document)` может помочь

Comment: Тоже не помогло

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#element").on(click,'*:not(this)',function()
{
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего надо добавить проверку, что кликнутый элемент не является самим `container`, то есть примерно так:

```
if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
```

В результате должно сработать:

```js
$(document).on('mouseup', function(e){
    var myDiv = $("#inner");
    if (!myDiv.is(e.target) && myDiv.has(e.target).length === 0) {
        console.log('Кликнули вне нужного дива');
    } else {
        console.log('Попали куда надо!');
    }
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

#inner {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="inner">
  
  </div>
</div>
```