# Как правильно сделать закрытие в раскрывающемся меню?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

```js
function menuToggle() {
  document.getElementById('navbar').style.display = 'flex';
}
```

```css
header {
  text-align: right;
}

header>i.header__menu-toggle {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
}

ul {
  border-bottom: 1px #dadad8 solid;
  display: none;
}

ul>a {
  height: 165px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1 1 384px;
  text-align: center;
}

ul>a.header__item-active {
  background-color: rgba(45, 204, 176, 0.25);
}

ul>a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(45, 204, 176, 0.25);
}
```

```html
<header>
  <button class="header__menu-toggle" onclick="menuToggle()">Menu</button>
  <nav>
    <ul id="navbar">
      <a href="">
        <li>Link</li>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <li>Link</li>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <li>Link</li>
      </a>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Есть вот такой код. Смог сделать раскрытие меню, но вот как сделать закрытие не могу понять.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверяем на наличие типа отображения `display`. Если он `flex`, значит надо сменить его на `none`, в ином случае - поставить его.

```js
function menuToggle() {
  var navBar = document.getElementById('navbar');
  navBar.style.display = (navBar.style.display == 'flex') ? 'none' : 'flex';
}
```

```css
header {
  text-align: right;
}

header>i.header__menu-toggle {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
}

ul {
  border-bottom: 1px #dadad8 solid;
  display: none;
}

ul>a {
  height: 165px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1 1 384px;
  text-align: center;
}

ul>a.header__item-active {
  background-color: rgba(45, 204, 176, 0.25);
}

ul>a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(45, 204, 176, 0.25);
}
```

```html
<header>
  <button class="header__menu-toggle" onclick="menuToggle()">Menu</button>
  <nav>
    <ul id="navbar">
      <a href="">
        <li>Link</li>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <li>Link</li>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <li>Link</li>
      </a>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое) Извините, а как сделать так, чтобы меню закрывалось не только при нажатии на кнопку, но и при нажатии на экран в любой части кроме меню?

Comment: @NikitaKnyazev https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/670046/191482 .... только пару моментов  с jquery заменить на чистый js

Comment: Спасибо, еще раз) Очень выручили